# django ForeignKey null = true

Tags: django, model

```
from django.db import models

class Story(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    news_type = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    category_id = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    author_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    image_caption = models.TextField(null=True)
    image_credit = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    image_full_url = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    body = models.TextField(null=True)
    summary = models.TextField(null=True)
    video_id = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    external_url = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    order = models.IntegerField(null=True)

class StoryFactBox(models.Model):
    story = models.ForeignKey('Story', null = True)
    body = models.TextField()

class StoryKeyword(models.Model):
    story = models.ForeignKey('Story', null = True)
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

What schema changes does `models.ForeignKey('Story', null = True)` cause to happen?

I am reading from the docs:

I want to use remove() and clear() and this is part of documentation.

In order to prevent database inconsistency, this method only exists on ForeignKey objects where null=True. If the related field can't be set to None (NULL), then an object can't be removed from a relation without being added to another. In the above example, removing e from b.entry_set() is equivalent to doing e.blog = None, and because the blog ForeignKey doesn't have null=True, this is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It causes no changes to the schema (just clarifying it only creates tables, doesn't modify), but upon syncdb, would create SQL statements *without* `NOT NULL`.

You can check the SQL output of the table definitions via `python manage.py sqlall my_app` and see for yourself!